# How to update on data restauration in a Laravel Eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to be able to run some code when an Eloquent model is loaded from my database. `fill()` does not seem to be the right method as it is not code when I load get my object from a query.

## Context *aka* "why would someone want to do that"

I wish my object to have some complex attributes which are currently represented as public properties, persisted as JSON on save and I need to restore them back on loading from database.

Laravel: 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you're looking for is `retrieved`, though mentioned in the `laravel` documentation,
not very obvious compared to the other events, you can either do it like this or delegate it to an observer class:

```
Model::retrieved(function(Model $model) {
    $model->foo = json_decode($this->json)['foo']; // '{"foo":"bar"}'
})
```

(and yes, this event runs after it has been retrieved from the database, but before your other code)

Comment: Thanks for that, do you have any idea where I should insert such a code ? Like right after my class declaration in the same file ? I like to keep things tidy ;)

Comment: Preferably in the `boot()` method of your `EventServiceProvider`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!